# how to mock static enum parameter using powermock

Tags: unit-testing, powermock, powermockito

I am using powermock and meet two problems like this:

```
public LogUtils {
    public static enum Type {
         **** 
    }

    public void log(Type type, Date date) {
         ***
    }
}

public class Service {
    public int call() {
       LogUtils.log(Type.T1, new Date());
       ***
       return *;
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestService {
     @Test
     @PrepareForTest(LogUtils.class)
     public void test() {
         Service service = new Service();
         PowerMockito.mockStatic(LogUtils.class);
         LogUtils.log(Type.T1, new Date());  // test here, but failed.
         service.
     }

     @Test
     @PrepareForTest(LogUtils.class)
     public void test2() {
         Service service = new Service();
         PowerMockito.mockStatic(LogUtils.class);
         LogUtils.log(Type.T1, new Date());
         int ret = service.call();
         Assert.isTrue(1, ret);
     }
}
```

For test1, it would throw Exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack in arraylength
Exception Details:
  Location:
    LogUtilss$Type.values()[LogUtils$Type; @137: arraylength
  Reason:
    Invalid type: 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[2])
  Current Frame:
    bci: @137
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/lang/Object', top, top, top, 'java/lang/Object' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Object', integer, 'java/lang/Object' }
```

it is caused by defining static enum in class instead of directly creating enum with single file. How to solve this problem as our codes almost define static enum in class?

For test2, if the first problem is solved, the direct call of LogUtils.log could be successfully skipped, but when call service.call(), couldn't skip.

Anyone could kindly help on this? Thanks a lot in advance.

I use powermock 1.6.5 and JDK1.7
Full code example:

```
public class LogUtils {

    public static enum Type {
        T(1),
        D(2);

        private int type;

        Type(int type) {
            type = type;
        }
    }

    public static void log(Type t, String msg) {
        System.out.println("skip this method");
    }
}

public class TestAction {

    public void test() {
        String msg = "logMsg";
        LogUtils.log(LogUtils.Type.T, msg);
    }
}

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class UnitTest {

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest(LogUtils.class)
    public void test() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LogUtils.class);
        TestAction a = new TestAction();
        LogUtils.log(LogUtils.Type.T, "test");
        a.test();
    }
}
```

Expect: no print for 'skip this method'.

Comment: Try disabling JVM verification by using the corresponding JVM switch when running your unit tests (I think you would be looking for -noverify). If that doesn't help ... you better turn the powermock forum at google groups; as chances are really low to get good answers on powermock questions on SO.

Comment: Which version Java and PowerMock do you use?

Comment: Besides what @ArthurZagretdinov requested, please provide a compilable sample to reproduce the issue (aka [sscce](http://sscce.org)) because your test with minor adjustments works fine with PowerMock 1.6.5.

Comment: @GhostCat partialy true, there are still a few around providing decent advice, but that also depends on the quality of the question and how deep in the framework the issue might be. Nonetheless your suggestion regarding the [forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/powermock) is sound advice as well

Comment: @ArthurZagretdinov  I use JDK1.7.0_67, and version of PowerMock is 1.6.5

Comment: @Morfic I use PowerMock1.6.5, and I just add my code sample. Could you help to advise what is your minor adjustments that works fine?

Comment: @Catrill I also failed to reproduce your issue. I check with PowerMock 1.6.5 and JDK 1.7_60, 1.7_79 and 1.8_77 (MacOS). 
I'd like recommend you: upgrade JDK to latest 1.7 JDK; check version of javassist. The javassist is accountable for generating bytecode when PowerMock modifies class, so I guess that some other dependency in your project also uses javassist, but different from powermock's version

Comment: The minor adjustments were necessary to make the code compile, eg: made `LogUtils.log()` static, corrected the incomplete `service.` call in the first test method, etc. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371284/bad-type-on-the-operand-stack-in-arraylength) sounds awfully similar and the JDK releases used in both the questions are rather close. If that's not helpful, you could try providing a [sscce](http://sscce.org) on github or similar so we can reproduce the issue locally.